# Executing blender with an executing python interpreter (ie parent process access to bpy.context)

Tags: python, scripting

Opening a blend file with blender does not localize the blender executable's python interpreter context
    eg a valid call to bpy.context from an external python interpreter does not appear to be faciliated by any documented facility
is it possible to open the blend file with blender with a provided python interpreter?

- The only other way to enable interaction with an opened file daemon would be to io with the executable on a port
- It's unlikely that python has any general purpose for sharing the python interpreter's context, ie an rpc api (that is callable from an external python interpreter in a interchangeable way) for:

  - general purpose memory reading/writing
  - command execution
  - any other constructs relevant to python